# Get Ypostion when scrolling page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I like to know where an object is on a page,

I did that function

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
    var elemento = $("#containerY");
    var positionY = elemento.position();
    $( ".valorY" ).text("top: " + positionY.top )
})
```

It works when page is loaded but `$( ".valorY" )` don't refresh de number and always show the same when page is scrolled,

What is wrong?

Comment: An element’s position on the page is not relative to the scroll bar position.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `($ window).scrollTop()` to get the y-coordinate of the top border of your browser and `($ 'yourElement').scrollTop()` to get its scroll-position. You can compare these to see what is on screen and what is not.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to subtract the window's scroll position from your elements position:

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
    var elemento = $("#containerY");
    var positionY = elemento.position();
    $( ".valorY" ).text("top: " + (positionY.top - $(window).scrollTop()) )
})
```

Answer (score -1):

thanks,
here is the solution!

> positionY.top - topBrowsere

and the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).scroll(function(){
    var elemento = $("#containerY");
    var positionY = elemento.position();
    var topBrowser = $(window).scrollTop();
    $( ".valorY" ).text("top: " + (positionY.top - topBrowser) );

    })
})
```